# I want to custom webauthn-register.ftl using React Keycloaktify, but in Keycloaktify not supported webauthn-register.ftl

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, freemarker

Im trying to customize keycloak theme spesific webauthn-register.ftl using Keycloaktify. But in the documentation, Keycloaktify does not yet provide a custom webauthn-register.ftl

Im trying convert from https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/login/webauthn-register.ftl ftl to react, but its doesnt work.